# How to add red wavy line below text on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How to add red wavy line below text on JTextField

like Spell Check of eclipse  , when you spell wrong, the wavy line under the word.

Comment: This is not possible, with `JTextField`, but probably with `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`. See the tutorial [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay thank all

i found a way, just exends jtextfield and override paint method.

[wavy textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V4Ng.png)

Comment: (1-) This is not an answer. How does a picture help anybody? Where is the actual painting code?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `Highlight` with a custom `HighlightPainter` to the text field.

Check out the [Squiggle Painter](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) for an example of this approach:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at javax.swing.JLayer. This class is a flexible and powerful decorator for Swing components, enabling you to draw on components and respond to events without modifying the underlying component.